# How to copy the content to clipboard using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, clip

I have the link ,when i click the link i have to copy the content to clipboard.
I am using below code but it is not copying.Any other code exist for copy to clipboard.I had tested so many codes ,but none of them useful.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.clipboard.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#val_link").click(function () {
    alert("Hello!");
        $("#val_link").clipboard({
            path: 'jquery.clipboard.swf',
            copy: function() {
                alert("Text copied.");
                return $("div#some-content").text();
            }    
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="val_link" value="ttttt">Link</a>
<div id="some-content">Text content to copy</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

http://www.shirmanov.com/2010/09/copy-to-clipboard-in-htmljavascript-and.html

Answer (score 0):

The .clipboard() function does the attaching of the click handlers for you. but it attaches it to an invisible element that it puts over the top of #val_link, in your case.

So, you have to put a click handler on #val_link to prevent its default use.

Then outside of that you add the clipboard function to it.

Essentially what you were doing was on click bind the clipboard handlers - my guess is if you clicked the link again then it would copy correctly, but then bind another set of events.

try:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.clipboard.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#val_link").click(function (o) {
    o.preventDefault();
    });
     $("#val_link").clipboard({
            path: 'jquery.clipboard.swf',
            copy: function() {
                alert("Text copied.");
                return $("div#some-content").text();
            }    
        });

});
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="val_link" value="ttttt">Link</a>
<div id="some-content">Text content to copy</div>
```